# If you have many columns some with NULL Values-- exclude without explicitly naming columns

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

If you have many columns eg a 100, but only want to return columns in a row which are NOT NULL is it possible to do so without explicitly naming each column?

Is there anyway around this?

Thank you.

Comment: it's probably not possible, but I would try normalize your table first...

Comment: Thank you , the program works with a set alg so it was denormalized for structural reasons...

Comment: The question is not quite clear to me. Do you mean *execute a query skipping columns which would have only nulls in the resultset*?

Comment: yes that’s what I mean

Comment: There are ways to force Postgres to do this, but it is quite complicated and inefficient. The general rule is that server is designed to provide data, and client to present it. You really need a good reason to break this rule. This is rather not the case, especially because it is a fairly easy task for a client application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to automatically omit columns where all values are null from a result set, no.

You'll have to handle this client side.

The good news is that sending nulls is extremely efficient, so the network impact of lots of null columns is minimal.